# How to post on a facebook test page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to post on a test Facebook page, but it wouldn't work here's what I did:

```
window.FB.api(
      '/https://graph.facebook.com/700757323715208/feed',
      'POST',
      {message:"Hello Fans", access_token:"{access_token}"
    },
      function(response) {
        console.log(response)      }
    );
```

and it's rendering this:

```
{id: "2568244933261615", url: "https://graph.facebook.com/700757323715208/feed"}
```

But it's supposed to render something like this :

```
{
  "id":"1116692661689527",
  "post_id":"546349135390552_1116692711689522"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct version:

```
window.FB.api(
    '/me/feed',
    'POST',
    {message:"Hello Fans", access_token:"{access_token}"
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

You do not need the Page ID, you have to use a Page Token of that Page anyway.